# Example of reactions series A → B followed by A + B → 2 C

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I'm currently writing about geometric numerical integration and I need an example of the following series of chemical reactions:

\begin{align}
\ce{A     &->[$k_1$] B} \tag{R1} \\
\ce{A + B &->[$k_2$] 2 C} \tag{R2}
\end{align}

The reason I want to use this form of the reaction is because
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}([\ce{A}] + [\ce{B}] + [\ce{C}]) = 0$$
and this would be an example of a *linear invariant*.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but what about O2 -> 2 O and  O2 + O -> O3 ? with d(2p(O2) + p(O) + 3p(O3))/dt=0.  Or the same with molar amounts or molar fractions. Formally with molar concentrations too, but that would be little unusual for gases. But possible.

Comment: Is that correct though? When I do my calculations I get $\frac{d[O_2]}{dt}=-k_1[O_2]-k_2[O_2][O]$, $\frac{d[O]}{dt}=2k_1[O_2]-k_2[O_2][O]$ and $\frac{d[O_3]}{dt}=k_2[O_2][O]$ and if you add these you get $\neq0$. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I was not addressing the kinetics just the mass inventory in context of the invariant. As the total mass of O allotropes is constant the given derivative is zero.

Comment: Let's go back a bit further. Why do you think your invariant holds? The overall reaction is $\ce{2A -> 2C}$. Are you applying steady state?

Comment: I haven't worked with kinetics in quite some time so I might be wrong. But I guessed that our total molar concentration should be an invariant since $\frac{d[A]}{dt}=-k_1 [A] - k_2 [A][B]$, $\frac{d[B]}{dt}=  k_1 [A] - k_2 [A][B]$ and $\frac{d[C]}{dt}= 2k_2 [A][B]$. And then we get that $\frac{d}{dt}([A]+[B]+[C])=(-k_1 [A]- k_2 [A][B]) + (k_1 [A] - k_2 [A][B]) + 2k_2 [A][B]=0$ therefore we have a linear invariant.

Comment: @zhe The invariant of his original supposed schema holds because of trivial total amount inventory, which is constant.

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t have just $\ce{A -> B -> C}$? There are many examples of that scheme.

Comment: Yes that would satisfy it but since I'm writing a paper on mathematics primarily I want something more computationally interesting.

Comment: But it is not that important to find a real example. I just thought people with more chemical knowledge might know some thing spontaneously.